# How is this variable scope resolving performed exactly?

Tags: javascript

While trying to understand how javaScript resolve variable, i wrote this code:

```
const a = 0;
var obj = {a: 1, foo: function(){console.log(a);}};
obj.foo();
```

I know that javaScript, like most of the programming languages, use the lexical/static scope to resolving variables.
But in this example, the lexical scope outside of foo function is obj scope and not global scope. 
So why do i get output `0` instead of `1` ?

Comment: Oh sorry ! My bad ! 
Yes that answered my question.
I just forgot, i am so sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the lexical scope outside of foo function is obj scope and not global scope.

There is no such thing as "obj scope" or "object scope". In Javascript, **every** variable name (or identifier) is scoped to either a block (such as inside a loop, or inside a function block), or is global.

An object isn't a block. Putting a property on an object does not create a new identifier; referencing such a property name as if it were a standalone variable does not work, because it's not an identifier in scope.

The only time in which something like this would be possible would be if you used `with` and referenced the property as if it was a standalone variable inside the `with` block, but `with` should never be used.

```js
const a = 0;
var obj = {
  a: 1,
  foo: function() {
    console.log(a);
  }
};
with (obj) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In an object with `{a: 1}` the 'a' is a string, not a variable. It does not assign 1 to 'a'. Instead it sets a key/value pair equivalent to `{ "a": 1 }`.

It has nothing to do with scope. The variable `a` defined in the first line is the only variable of that name and never has its value changed in the code you gave.

Note also that you defined it as `const` meaning it cannot be assigned a different value.

Answer (score 1):

If you need reference the `a` object property, is necessary use `this.a`, because `a` without this is the global variable.

```js
const a = 0;

var obj = {a: 1, foo: function(){console.log(this.a);}};

obj.foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only one `a`, and it's declared on your first line. 
In order to use this object's variables, you have to use this. For example:

```
const a = 0
var obj = { a: 1, foo: function() { console.log(this.a) } } 
obj.foo(); // 1
```

When you use `this.a`, that's the same thing, if you use `obj.a` outside of this object.

To understand this better, you can check the example below:

```
const mark = 10
const obj = {
  name: 'Sardor',
    mark: mark,
    setMark: function(num) { this.mark = num },
    getMark: function() { console.log(this.mark) }
}

obj.getMark() // 10
obj.setMark(8)
obj.getMark() // 8
console.log(mark) // 10
```

It means, that you filled mark by the `date` of `num`. Then you called `.setMark()` function of `obj` and changed its value to 8. But you didn't change the variable mark, that is outside of obj. That's why finnaly you have 8 in obj.mark and 10 in mark.

Advice: read more about `this`